# Как реализовать регистрацию пользователя через номер телефона

Tags: android

как можно реализовать регистрацию пользователя через номер телефона. Firebase не подходит потому что, в нём нельзя хранить данные российского пользователя по закону РФ.
И именно интересует как сделать смс регистрацию, чтобы отправителем с кодом было имя как и в других популярных сервисах.

Comment: Ищите платный сервис какой-то. Первое что в гугле нашёл - от пчелиного оператора, около 3 рублей за смс

Comment: По моему на Laravel можно организовать отр авторизацию